# using jQuery to get other buttons not clicked in a div

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML div

```
<div id="buttons">
   <button type="button" id= "button_1" >I am button one</button></br></br>
   <button type="button" id= "button_2">I am button two</button></br ></br>
</div>
```

I have attached the following jQuery handler

```
$("#buttons").click(function(event) {

}
```

I want to put in code that colors the clicked button’s label type color to red and the other button or buttons (I may add more)  label type color back to black. Using this type of code:

```
 $("#button_1").css("color","red”);
```

I thought that using .not would work to get me the unclicked divs, something like:
   `$("#buttons").not(“#” + event.target.id).css("color”,”black”)` would set all unclicked
buttons- basically those that are not event.target - to black, then I would set the clicked on to red `$(“#” + event.target.id).css("color”,”black”)` -

It is not working- hence my query. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [**.siblings()**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) , like so:

```
$("#button_1").siblings().css("color","black");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
$(".buttonClass").click(function(event) {
    $(this).css("color","red");
    $(".buttonClass").not(this).css("color","black");
}
```

where `buttonClass` is the class of the buttons. You could replace `".buttonClass"` with just `button` depending on your html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.siblings()` selector to select siblings (yes, really):

```
$('#buttons button').click(function() {
  $(this).css('color', 'red').siblings().css('color', 'black');
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Bsum5/1/**

---

A better approach would be to use CSS and just add a class:

```
$('#buttons button').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});​
```

And use this CSS:

```
​.active {
    color: red;
}​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Bsum5/3/**